# User.Identity.Name = "" (anonymous) but Windows auth is enabled?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ldap, windows-authentication

I created an ASP.NET MVC app with the following override via a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` implementation:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
}
```

However, within this method, `httpContext.User.Identity.Name` is "".  I need to get a handle to the current `Identity.Name` so I can retrieve some data based on that value. I have the following entries in `web.config`:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"  />
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

At minimum, I think that the MVC site should prompt me for credentials with the configuration above, right?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the network user ID with the following alternate code:

```
Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
```

Are there any implications or impacts of using this code as opposed to:

```
httpContext.User.Identity.Name
```